# IFD0 - exif_read_data shows question mark "???"

Tags: php, exif

I am using `exif_read_data($file, "IFD0")` to read the `IFD0` data but when I make a print (`print_r`) the `Comments` section shows `????????????????????????????` instead of comments. If I call only `exif_read_data($file, 0, true)` from the PHP documentation then the `comments` section from the `IFD0` is shown. That's happens in PHP > 5.3. In PHP <= 5.3 it works well.

```
[Comments] => ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

What to do?

**EDIT**

I have tried to use only `exif_read_data($file, 0, true)` as I told you above, and it shows the comment but when I check the source code the comment contains a symbol (i can't add it here, because it is auto-deleted - it is a square with 00 and 00 in it) after each character.

Answer (score 3):

is an encoding problem. This should solve the problem:

```
ini_set('exif.decode_unicode_motorola', 'UCS-2LE');
```